# Alternative for NSKeyedArchiver/ NSKeyedUnarchiver iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I have a dictionary that is written into a file after archiving it `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary]` . I fetch the file contents and transferring the archived data to my peer devices through multipeer. Then, in my peer device, I am unarchiving the data using `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]`. But, it is returning nil while unarchiving it, though data is present in it.

I am suspecting that the content is huge in file. Is there any alternative for `NSkeyedArchiver`/ `NSKeyedUnarchiver` ?

Code:
Archiving:

```
[[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary] writeToFile:fileAtPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

Transferring:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath] ;
```

Unarchiving:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: how you are archiving and unarchiving? write your code

Answer (score 0):

Try to write data like below,

```
 [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
```

here `data` means `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary]` your archived data.

otherwise archived and unarchived method is fine.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: dint work..same issue, dictionary is nil while unarchiving or I get exception 'incomprehensible archive'